# How to Perform Stress/Load test on a chrome extension using Jmeter?

Tags: automated-tests, load-testing

The title explains it.

I have a chrome extension that I have been working on, which shows relevant dcouments and data from a DB related to the webpage open on the main tab. And now I have to stress test it by checking how many users can it handle at once after logging in and clicking on the search "All" documents.

I have been trying to find some good tutorials, but all i get is testing using different jmeter extensions for chrome.

If jmeter can't be used for stress testing an extension, can you share a better alternative for the task?

Answer (score 0):

The title doesn't explain it.

How many users can use a chrome extension concurrently? Only one. Therefore Stress/Load test is not applicable, what you can do is to [profile it](https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/ab6a6aefcda21dd2db69c7eaa7bf3332).

If you want to add test automation on top of it, i.e. to measure how fast it opens, switches between screens/views, react on clicks, etc. you can consider using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)) but again it will be only simulation of 1 user.

Another story is load testing the [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontend_and_backend), for example if chrome extension is connecting to some remote server and you need to check how does the server handle hundreds/thousands of the extension users. In this case most probably you will be able to use JMeter to simulate multiple concurrent users using the chrome extension by replicating their network footprint using appropriate JMeter [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), in case of [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol you can even record the requests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and replay it with [increased number of users](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users).

Comment: OK, the HTTP Test script recorder seems something that can help out. I'll look into it. Thanks